# How to create package for my Qt5 app in Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, installation

I have made a Qt application on Ubuntu. My application's binary is available in the `/home/<user>/sample/` folder. How can I allow users to install the application on Ubuntu by including Qt dependencies? I am not very familiar with Linux system commands. If you could provide step by step instructions it would be great.

Comment: There are already a handful of questions about this, as well as a step by step guide in the Qt manual: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html